# TTreeView custom draw of selected item

Tags: delphi, windows-8, treeview, delphi-xe

I'm trying to emulate Outlook 2013 left pane tree view menu for my application. I'm using CustomDraw because I only want to change some simple font and background properties.

Here's what I want:

[image: Outlook 2013 sidebar menu]

However, I always get the default selected drawing for both selected and hot tracked nodes. I don't have Windows 7 or XP to see if this is the normal behavior or if it's something related with my OS (Windows 8).

Here's what I'm getting:

[image: Bad imitation of an Outlook 2013 style sidebar menu]

Here's my code:

```
procedure TMainForm.TreeView1CustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomTreeView;
  Node: TTreeNode; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  if Node.Level = 1 then
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Size := Sender.Canvas.Font.Size + 2;

  if cdsHot in State then
    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := $00F7E6CD
  else if (cdsSelected in State) or (cdsFocused in State) or
    (cdsChecked in State) then
    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := $00F2F2F2
  else
    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := $00DEDEDE;
  DefaultDraw := true;
end;
```

How can I draw a different colored background for selected and hot items?

Comment: I believe you have to un-theme the control for this to work. Disable runtime themes for the application, or at least call `SetWindowTheme` with empty strings on the treeview.

Comment: Perhaps you can start with VirtualStringTree ?

Comment: Actually, I think I'm not correct. The docs specifically mention for toolbars that you have to disable visual styles by calling SetWindowTheme, but no mention of any other control. [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff919569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, you should post an answer since you basically solved it in comments, didn't even see it, removing my answer.

Comment: @Peter - No problem, I'm fine with not posting an answer, please reinstate your answer. Actually I'll vote for yours later if someone does not come up with an explanation. I won't be surprised if MS' document turns out to be incomplete or some such.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, I've updated my answer with what I hope is a half decent explanation :p

Comment: @Peter, thanks for that, although I'm not exactly sure if the item states documentation should account for custom drawing. You can substitute the [treeview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) counterparts though (TVIS_SELECTED, ...) ;).

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, the problem I had with that is if you look at `procedure TTreeNode.SetState` the lparam of the TVM_SETITEM can contain `TVIS_FOCUSED` flag but when I checked the MS documentation [Tree-View Control Item States](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759985(v=vs.85).aspx) there's no mention of the TVIS_FOCUSED only TVIS_SELECTED. weird!

Comment: @Peter - Indeed, it seems that there's no TVIS_FOCUSED. [*The new versions of Commctrl.h do not define TVIS_FOCUSED. This style was never implemented and is no longer defined.*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/166471/en-us).

Comment: @Arioch'The - I was thinking about it but I really don't like using VTV unless I have to...

Comment: making full VTV drawing is tedious, i agree. But using VST might end with rather little tweaking

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the following :

[image]

```
type
  TTreeView = class(Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeView)
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
  end;


uses uxtheme;

procedure TTreeView.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited;
  SetWindowTheme(Handle, nil , nil);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

   TreeView1.Font.Name := 'Segoe UI';
   TreeView1.HotTrack := True;
   TreeView1.Font.Size := TreeView1.Font.Size + 1;
   TreeView1.Color := $00DEDEDE;

end;

procedure TForm1.TreeView1CustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomTreeView;
  Node: TTreeNode; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin

   if cdsFocused in State then begin
     Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := $00F2F2F2;
     Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clblack;
     Sender.Canvas.Font.Style := Sender.Canvas.Font.Style + [fsBold];
   end else if cdsHot in State then
    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := $00F7E6CD
   else
    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := $00DEDEDE;

end;
```

---

**Explanation:**

The Microsoft documentation on this is incredibly fuzzy, what I can say with certainty is that whenever an action (*Selection, Hot tracking , De-Selection etc...*) is performed on an Item (Node), a specific message is sent, this message includes the state of the Node via the parameters flag which at the very end internally decides how the Item should be updated visually based on the current Windows Theme.

This is the probable cause as to why disabling themes for the TreeView component removes the default selection rectangle & theme coloring. The documentation for the [Control state flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) supports this theory in partial.

Comment: Any explanation for why you have to disable theming on the control for coloring to work?

Comment: Because with theming the selected items are basically masked. His colors do get drawn but under the actual themed selection area.

Comment: that's not correct, but it's also not what I meant to ask. Not correct because those colors are returned with clrText and clrTextBk members of the NMTVCUSTOMDRAW structure to be used by the system when drawing. The system either use those colors or not, there's no painting over. But anyway, what I meant to ask is do you have any MS reference for disabling theming on the control? Otherwise the behavior you observe is also the behavior what I observe.

Comment: That's interesting, good to know. I don't have any MS reference, I often come back to dealing with this issue a lot and it's always the Win theming that is the culprit.

Comment: +1 as I agree theming is overriding custom drawing. I liked the code only answer better though.. <g>

Comment: Call to SetWindowTheme needs to be in CreateWnd in case of window re-creation.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, I agree, I've edited and updated my answer to what I hope now includes a more accurate explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the theming tip. Indeed, the colors are fixed with this approach, but the drawing of the collapsed/expanded arrows defaults to the old style plus/minus sign, which is not what I want.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera, that was not part of your question so I didn't bother focusing on it. In short, there's two ways, one being that you uncheck the `showButtons` property and draw the button yourself using `StateImages` and `TTreeNode.StateIndex` or the other being that you set the `DefaultDraw` property of the Event to False, this will ommit any windows default drawing of the button but it also means you will have to draw the entire control yourself.

Comment: Bummer. I don't like custom drawing much.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera, well just by using the `TreeViewCustomDrawItem` event you are already custom drawing. My suggestion to you is to go with the StateImages as I mentioned, this is a very nice, fast and easy way to solve this.

Comment: @PeterVonča - tried a quick solution with `StateImages` and it is not as easy nor convenient as one would wish (mimicking the handler with an image leaves unresolved the issue of clicking on it.) I think I'll keep working using your solution and I'll see how feasible is to replace the buttons with my own images.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera, alright, that was just top of my head, I don't think that implementing a HitTest would take much work tho. I would suggest that if this is so important that you simply ask a new question but don't forget to accept this one first ! xD